# Inconsistent behavior when updating a background image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 buttons that have background images. Before changing an image on 'button1', I am making sure that all of the other buttons return to their original state. After that, I am changing 'button1' to a new image (I am not sure if this is the best way to do this).

About half of teh times I visit the page, this works as intended. The other times, 'button1' does not get set and remains unchanged.  Why does this not work the same each time? How can I make the behaviour be consistent?

```
document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/buttonUnClicked.png')";
document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/buttonUnClicked.png')";
document.getElementById("button4").style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/buttonUnClicked.png')";
document.getElementById("button5").style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/buttonUnClicked.png')";

document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/buttonClicked.png')";
```

Comment: Please share your code in a fiddle

Comment: Why wouldn't you set the `background-image: url('Images/buttonUnClicked.png');` in the CSS as the default then only change the one that you need to (i.e. button1)... I'm not 100% sure, but your issues might be the fact that you are reloading background images. you could also try `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to try and reduce unnecessary (non-visible) overhead.

Comment: I find that this type of inconsistant behaviour is due to a JavaScript error occuring on the page. Open the debug console and check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the description of radio inputs. You don't need JavaScript for that.
The trick is to style the labels to the radio buttons and hide the buttons themselves.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="button" name="button" id="button1"/>
      <label for="button1"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

(add as many buttons as you want)

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.button {
  visibility:hidden;
  clip:rect(0 0 0 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 9999px;
}

label {
  background-image: url("Images/buttonUnClicked.png");
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.button:checked + label {
  background-image: url("Images/buttonClicked.png");
}
```

I made this [**demo**](http://codepen.io/climbinghobo/pen/iCamL) for you on CodePen.